# How to detect an Outgoing call in android

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager, outgoing-call

Just I want to know if there is a code that can detect if 'im calling someone with the default android phone app..
this is my code here and of course I need more hints

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            call = true;
            Log.v("OUTGOING", String.valueOf(call));
            //Do-NOTHING
        } else {
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                if (call == false) {
                    Log.v("OUTGOING", String.valueOf(call));
                    Log.v("CALL", "Call from " + numberPhone);
                    numberPhone = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the necessary broadcast receiver in your app's manifest?

Comment: @rodit I did that already both for permission and intent-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 public OutgoingReceiver() {
 }

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

     Toast.makeText(ctx, 
       "Outgoing: "+number, 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

And set Receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

you have to register the intent

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: S.Raut could you explain the code? I just neeed to know the condition where the outgoing call is detected
I already named my class as incomingCall so I focused from the first time in incoming calls so in the case of outgoing call the app will do nothing..

Comment: **For outgoing calls, the system sends a broadcast action android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.** we have create a Broadcast Receiver to detect it named **OutgoingReceiver**

Comment: So you mean that I need to create another class with another broadcastreceiver?

Comment: Please read carefully the new Google security regarding PROCESS_OUTGOUNG_CALLS permission(the app could be banned): https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303